# Исключить дату если дата вставлена в реал тайм или возврат на NULL

Tags: java, android

Как я могу исключить добавление даты если дата вставлена в реальном времени , то есть если дату кликнули случайно , так как при клике на дату она сразу берёт зависимость от нынешней даты , а мне надо что бы была возможность выбрать дату в виде нет даты.

**Вот мой код даты:**

```
btnDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // show date picker dialog
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // set default date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // get selected date
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = month;
        mDay = day;

        // show selected date to date button
        btnDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(mYear).append("/")
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                .append(mDay).append(" "));
    }
}
```

Comment: а как определить - случайно нажали или нет? сделай кнопки подтверждения да/нет

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов - вы имеете ввиду показать сначала диалог?